# job oracle одновременный insert

Tags: oracle, insert, jobscheduler

в данный момент у меня есть 2 задания, которые начинают обрабатываться в одно и то же время,
оба работают через процедуру.
в курсор записывается результат селекта и потом с помощью loop данные записываются в таблицу,
так как jobs работают одновременно и записывают данные одновременно в одну и ту же таблицу не приведет ли это к тому, что какие-то данные будут перезатираться, проще говоря не записываться?
и из-за того что это происходит одновременно, не приведет ли это к тому, что задания будут отрабатываться дольше?

часть процедуры

```
open cursor_1;
   loop
    fetch cursor_1 into id;
    exit when cursor_1%NOTFOUND;
    INSERT INTO TEST(id) VALUES (id);
    commit;
  end loop;
  close cursor_1;
```

Если к моему вопросу есть уточнения или вопрос задан не по правилам, пожалуйста, уведомьте меня об этом в комментариях.

Comment: Если у вас простые insert, то на производительность не должно повлиять. По времени будет одно и то же(примерно), если пускать 2 задания последовательно. insert это вставка данных. Если у вас в заданиях логика более сложная, с update, то это может повлиять на все что угодно, вплоть до DEAD LOCK и остановки заданий.

Comment: нет, у меня только insert, получается данные будут записываться корректно, не смотря на то, что они записываются одновременно ?

Comment: Да. И еще можно commit вынести за цикл, если строк не очень много. Если строк много вставляется, то коммитить пачками по 1000 или по 10000.

Comment: И еще, если у вас цикл внутри ничего не делает с каждой строкой - не проверяет и не меняет данные из курсора, то как вариант заменить всю эту конструкцию на `insert as select`. Это явно работать будет быстрее, чем инсерт из цикла построчно